# Can I receive one row per predecessor?

Tags: excel, add-in, rally

This forum has been very helpful to understand the Rally Excel Add-in.

I am able to extract the Predecessors for a user story.

If there are more than one then they are all placed into one cell separated by a coma.

My syntax is :AcceptedDate,FormattedID,Predecessors.FormattedID

The results is;
2012-11-05T14:38:24.963Z    US22938 US19926,
                                        US27528,
                                        US28467,
                                        US29310

The Predecessors are all in one cell: US19926,US27528,US28467,US29310

Is there a way to receive each predecessor in it's own cell? Row?

Regards,
Jim

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there's not a way to accomplish this using the Excel add-in. As a workaround, it would be possible to split these out into cells or rows using Excel parsing functions and/or VBA though.

Comment: Thank You for your fast response.